# ComponentDidMount called lots of times

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I'm trying to fetch data from my database using ComponentDidMount, this is my code

```js
class ExistingWorkouts extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
    
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('mount')
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/getworkouts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='existing-container'>
                <h5>Back and Biceps</h5>
                <h6>4 exercises</h6>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default ExistingWorkouts;
```

And this is my code from the backend

```js
app.get('/getworkouts', (req, res) => {
    db.select('*').from('routines')
        .where('userid',  '=', user.id)
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).json(data)
        })
        .catch(err => status(400).json("Error getting workouts"))
})
```

When my react app loads, the data from my backend gets sent 15 times, that means ComponentDidMount ran 15 times and I dont understand why that is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've realised why this happens, such a dumb mistake. The component `ExistingWorkouts` is being rendered 15 times by its parent component, therefore ComponentDidMount runs 15 times. So I have to use ComponentDidMount in the parent component and not the child one